# how to test ntp servers as real servers that responding without using ping test

Tags: ping, redhat-enterprise-linux, ntp, protocol, icmp

we have bash script that configured the `chrony.conf`

script check if ping is ok on `ntp1` and `ntp2` ( ntp servers )

and then script insert the ntp servers to `/etc/chrony.conf` ( only if ping success )

example from bash script:

```
ping -c 1 ntp1

if [[ $? -eq 0 ]];then
echo "server ntp1 iburst" >> /etc/chrony.conf
else
echo "sorry so much but no ping to ntp1 server , /etc/chrony.conf will not configured "
exit 1
fi


ping -c 1 ntp2

if [[ $? -eq 0 ]];then
echo "server ntp2 iburst" >> /etc/chrony.conf
else
echo "sorry so much but no ping to ntp2 server , /etc/chrony.conf will not configured "
exit 1
fi
```

the problem is that sometimes the user decided to disable the `ping` or `icmp`

**then in that case** the scenario that we checked the ping isn't relevant , and we cant add the lines to `/etc/chrony.conf`

so we want to know how to **test** the `ntp1` and `ntp2` servers in order to add **ntp1** and `ntp2` to chrony configuration

for example if `ntp1` and `ntp2` not seems to be as ntp servers , then we will not add them to chrony configuration

Comment: Please [do not cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/355310). For the record, the other copy is [on Unix & Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/703679/108618).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An ntp server can be tested by asking it for the date using the
[ntpdate command](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ntpdate).

For example:

```
ntpdate -q pool.ntp.org
```

The parameter `-q` is for query only, don't set the clock.

The command will return the exit code of `0` if successful.

Comment: `ntpdate` ships with `ntp` package.